# esri-leaflet dynamicMapLayer layerDefs

Tags: esri-leaflet

I have a dynamicMapLayer with a layer definition set to filter out certain features, the problem is that the popup which is bound to this layer does not recognize the layer definition and will display information for features not drawn on the map.

```
<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([38.95, -81.203], 8);
  L.esri.basemapLayer('Gray').addTo(map);
  var mines = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
url:'http://atlas.wvgs.wvnet.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Coal_Web_Mercator/All_Mining_WM/MapServer/',
    layers: [1],
    layerDefs: {1:"SEAM = 'Redstone'"},
    opacity: 0.5,
    useCors: false
  }).addTo(map);
  var popupTemplate = "<h3>{SEAM}</h3><br><small>Name: {MINE_NAME}<small>";
  mines.bindPopup(function (error, featureCollection) {
    if(error || featureCollection.features.length === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return L.Util.template(popupTemplate, featureCollection.features[0].properties);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been a bug and the problem has been resolved in [pass through layer definitions when binding a popup](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/pull/978).